# How do I set variable (changing) attribute names with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to set a variable attribute name, ie `<a data-33="string">`, with 33 being a random number generated by Math.random().

I have tried:

```
var randomNum1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (200 - 100 + 1)) + 100;
var attrb = 'data-' + randomNum1.toString(); 
$(this).attr({
    attrb : 'someString',
    attrb2 : 'someString'
});
```

But instead of adding an attribute of data-randomNumber="someString", it adds attrb="someString"

I'm trying to pass multiple attributes. I know I'm missing a basic javascript concept, but any help would be appreciated!

Comment: you can't use an object literal to do that...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using a variable for a Javascript object key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274242/using-a-variable-for-a-javascript-object-key)

Comment: @Bergi Not exactly a duplicate since the user is unaware of proper usage and his understanding is will be different.

Comment: @user3251562 IMHO do try to understand javascript objects and the way they can be accessed. Only knowledge of JQuery wont help you write good code.

Comment: +1 @LearningNeverStops Its crucial that people understand pure JavaScript with its objects and other concepts. JQuery is spoiling people :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are doing, `{attrb: "something", attr2: "something"}`, the keys, `attrb` and `attr2` are not evaluated and are taken as it is. So you cannot use variables over there.

To solve your problem, what you can do is, call the `attr()` method with two arguments - 1: the attribute, 2: the value:

```
var el = $(this);
el.attr(attrb, 'someString');
el.attr(attrb2, 'someString');
```

In this case the first argument of `attr()` is evaluated and the variable is substituted with the value.

Comment: Thanks, admittedly I am spoiled with JQ, but am learning JS quickly with help from people like you!

Comment: Welcome! :) This will help A LOT. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var randomNum1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (200 - 100 + 1)) + 100;
var attrb = 'data-' + randomNum1.toString();
$(this).attr(attrb,"someString");
$(this).attr(attrb2,"someString");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var randomNum1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (200 - 100 + 1)) + 100;
var atts = {};
   atts['data-' + randomNum1.toString()] = 'someString';
$(this).attr(atts);
```

Setting the names of object literals with variables works using square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has a built in `data()` function see [here](http://api.jquery.com/data/) for the proper method documentation. 
As for your specific propblem I would suggest

```
var randomNum1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (200 - 100 + 1)) + 100;
var attrb = randomNum1.toString(); 
var $this = $(this);
$this.data(attrb, 'someString');
$this.data(attrb2, 'somestring');
```

Comment: Object literals are taken as it is, `attrb` wont be replaced with its value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function getRandom(){
    return (Math.floor(Math.random() * (200 - 100 + 1)) + 100).toString();
}

var attrs = {};

attrs["data-" + getRandom()] = "something";
attrs["data-" + getRandom()] = "something";
attrs["data-" + getRandom()] = "something";

//console.log(attrs);

$(".target").attr(attrs);
```

This will do something like:

```
<div class="target" data-108="something" data-123="something" data-107="something">something</div>
```

*What I am doing is first creating the attributes obj separately, then passing in the .attr() method of jQuery.*

<kbd>Working Demo</kbd>: http://jsfiddle.net/xBdcq/

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
$(this).attr('attr-'+b,'somestring');
```